# How can I set ul background image fadeIn with CSS3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an Unordered List in my page. Each li elements displayed with CSS3 rotate animation.
I want to set background image with FadeIn effect just after li animation finished.

I write "addbg" Class for ul like this:

```
ul.addbg{
    background: transparent url(../img/circle-line.png) no-repeat 49% 94px;
    -webkit-transition:background 5.6s;  
    -moz-transition:background 5.6s;  
    -o-transition:background 5.6s;  
    transition:background 5.6s; 

}
```

but nothing happen!

How can I do that?

My ul is like this:

```
             <ul class="addbg">
                <li>
                    <span>Text1</span>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>Text2</span>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>Text3</span>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>Text4</span>

                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: You can't `transition` `background-image`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't transition `background-image` property, however you can set the `background-image` to its `:after` :pseudo-element and `transition` its `opacity`.

Here's a quick example.

```css
#image {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
#image:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/300/100);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  z-index: -1;
}
#image:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">Some Content</div>
```

---

If you want to add a delay instead of `:hover`, you could define `@keyframes` and add `delay`(`3s` in the example below) to the animation and set the `opacity` of the `#image:after` to `1` after the animation has ended using JavaScript.

`animation: fadeIn 1s 1 3s` - `fadeIn` is the `animation-name`, `1s` is the `animation-duration`, `1` is the `animation-iteration` and `3s` is the `animation-delay`.

```js
var img = document.getElementById('image');
var event = ['webkitAnimationEnd', 'animationend'];

for (i = 0; i < event.length; i++) {
  img.addEventListener(event[i], function() {
    var ss = document.styleSheets;
    for (j = 0; j < ss.length; j++) {
      var rules = ss[j];
      for (k = 0; k < rules.cssRules.length; k++) {
        var r = rules.cssRules[k];
        if (r.selectorText == "#image::after" || r.selectorText == "#image:after") {
          r.style.opacity = 1;
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#image {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
#image:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/300/100);
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s 1 3s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s 1 3s;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="image">Some Content</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you could do a pure JavaScript animation using `setTimeout()` for the delay and `setInterval()` for the animation without using `transition` or `@keyframes`.

```js
var ss = document.styleSheets;
for (i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
  var rules = ss[i];
  for (j = 0; j < rules.cssRules.length; j++) {
    var r = rules.cssRules[j];
    if (r.selectorText == "#image::after" || r.selectorText == "#image:after") {
      var op = 0;
      setTimeout(function() {
        var fadeIn = setInterval(function() {
          r.style.opacity = op;
          op += 0.005;
          if (op > 1) {
            clearTimeout(fadeIn);
          }
        }, 7)
      }, 3000)
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#image {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
#image:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/300/100);
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">Some Content</div>
```

Comment: @chipChocolate.py - Excuse me, Can I send my code to You and you see why it doesn't work true?

Comment: @keykan - Sure, you can create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and give me a link.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py - It works perfect in Fiddle and CodePen. But when I put your code in my project, it doesn't work good. even I put the code in a single HTML file, But it doesn't work at all ! :(

Comment: @keykan - If your site is live, could you give me a link to it?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py No it doesn't. I'm sorry. It's in developing (Local right now).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67786/discussion-between-chipchocolate-py-and-keykan).